# Django subquery with ManyToMany

Tags: django, database, orm

I have the following database schema:

```python
class Psychologist:
    availabilities = models.ManyToManyField(Availability, blank=True)
    taken_availabilities = models.ManyToManyField(Availability, blank=True, related_name='taken_availabilities')
```

And I want to filter all the availabilities that at least one Psychologist have and the same Psychologists don not have it in `taken_availabilities`.

For example, if:

`psy1 has: availabilities=1am; taken_availabilities=
psy2 has availabilities=2am,3am; taken_availabilities=2am`

This query should result in `1am, 3am` (because the only psychologist that have 2am, has it taken)

I could come up with this:

```python
Availability.objects.filter(psychologist__in=Psychologist.objects.filter(availabilities__id=F('id')).exclude(taken_availabilities__id=F('id')))
```

But it doesn't work, it shows all the Availabilities the psychologist have, doesn't matter if the only psychologists that have it have it taken.

Any help with this?

Comment: What about this ? `Availability.objects.filter(psychologist__isnull=False, taken_availabilities__isnull=True)` ?

Comment: I think that would retrieve all the Availability that at least someone hast AND nobody has marked as taken.